Will Moshiach need to PROVE he is a male line descendant of King David?
Would it be a requirement for Moshiach to be able to prove that he is a descendant of King David or at least have a family mesorah that he is?
Or is it more of a case that once we see that someone is Moshiach it is obvious that he is descended from King David? Is it enough to simply not be a Kohen or Levi? Or I guess also a Benyomonite?

The lineage aspect of Moshiach is only a very small part of the equation. Most people today don’t have any kind of actual documentation and rely on family tradition. Of those with documentation, of what I have looked at, even there, the lineage only goes back so far and says there is a tradition that this historical individual was from the house of David. But once resurrection occurs, there will be eye witness testimony for verification from generation to generation.

If someone accomplishes everything needs to but doesn't have a written document showing his lineage would you still doubt him for not having paperwork?

"In the future, the Messianic king will arise and renew the Davidic dynasty, restoring it to its initial sovereignty. He will build the Temple and gather the dispersed of Israel." (Rambam, Hilchos Melachim UMilchamos, Perek 11, Halacha 1). From this, we can deduce (?) that we can consider him Moshiach, right?

I hope not. That may prove bad news for Chabad.

I wouldn’t have thought so if Eliyahu Hanavi accompanies him.

@chortkov2 You mean, Messianic Chabad.

Probably Eliyahu testifies to his lineage.
